# How to Save Test Results in Postman

Tags: testing, postman

I have an API Collection in Postman, and I have saved a few examples for each request.

When I try to save the Test Results though, only the JavaScript code is saved in the examples, and not the actual results (same goes for when exporting the whole API Collection).

Is there any other way I can do this to export the Test Results too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know, you can't save test results but you can run test collection on [Newman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/) and save the result

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a report, it will include all the results of your test.

You can install  [newman-reporter-htmlextra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra) with the following command:

```
npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
```

Then you can execute Newman with report enabled:

```
newman run xxxxx.json -r htmlextra
```

The resulting HTML report will be saved in `newman` directory on the current directory.